# How to execute programmatic workflows in Elsa Workflow

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have programmatically created Workflow Json say Pipe1, I want to know how I can execute it like other workflows that we create using Elsa Dashboard by clicking on execute button.
Usually, it hits URL like /WorkflowName/execute, but this is not working in case of programmatic workflows (the ones that we create using JSON file).

I want to know how I can programmatically execute my custom workflow (created using JSON file) using some API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute *any* workflow via the REST API, even workflows created in code or using JSON.

However, these workflows need to be available from the **workflow registry**.
If your JSON workflows are provided via a workflow provider (any `IWorkflowProvider` implementation like `BlobStorageWorkflowProvider`), then they will be part of the workflow registry.

For example, if you store workflow JSON files in your application in a folder called `workflows`, you can configure the **blob storage** provider like this:

```cs
// Configure blob storage for blob storage workflow storage provider. 
services.Configure<BlobStorageWorkflowProviderOptions>(options => options.BlobStorageFactory = () => StorageFactory.Blobs.DirectoryFiles(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Workflows")));
```

You can find the sample application here: https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/tree/master/src/samples/aspnet/Elsa.Samples.SignalApi